# Handle JSON calls in WCF to single URL with method name contained in request body

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

We are replicating an existing service and need to offer the exact same contract.

Requests are posted to a single URL with the method name contained in the request body.

For example the request body of a call to LoginService.Login:

All calls will be made to: http://example.com/json

```
{"id": "","method":"LoginService.Login","params":{"aUserID":"flip","aPassword":"1234-613E-1240-C55D-9853F37A41B2"}}
```

How can we accomplish this within WCF?  The response should also be JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't know what I wanted was called jsonrpc.  Luckily somebody already tackled this problem:

[Implement JSON-RPC in WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17963977/implement-json-rpc-in-wcf)